# Why am I using too much disk space with this code?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract some readable variables from AD, the following works.

```
$user = get-aduser "username" -Properties memberof, emailAddress, extensionattribute2, manager, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, url

$groups = ForEach ($group in $user.memberof){(Get-ADGroup $group).Name}

$groupStr = $groups -join "; " #Change "; " to "`r`n" for line break seperator

$user | Select-Object `

@{N="firstName";E={$_.GivenName}}, `
@{N="lastName";E={$_.Surname}}, `
@{N="email";E={$_.EmailAddress}}, `
@{N="businessArea";E={$_.extensionattribute2}}, `
@{N="accountName";E={$_.SamAccountName}}, `
@{N="manager";E={$_.Manager -replace '^CN=|,.*$'}}, `
@{N="office";E={$_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName}}, `
@{N="standardProfile";E={$_.url}}, `

@{n='Groups'; e={$groupStr}} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation "c:\out.csv"
```

However when I swap `Get-aduser "username"` to: `Get-aduser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase “ou=redacted,ou=UserAccounts,dc=redacted,dc=com”`

It runs for a fairly long time and fills up the last 40gb on the disk and errors out as it's run out of space.

I know in the past I've wildcarded -Properties and run into similar issues (obvious now I understand) but I'm not sure what's causing the issue this time round.

`{Enabled -eq $true}` & `-SearchBase`limit it to about 4 thousand users which I wouldn't think would take this long to run, and I've no idea what's using up the disk space.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$groups` will contain all of the groups for all enabled AD Users if you don't pick a specific user object for `get-aduser`. This is because `$user.memberof` will return all groups for every user in the `$user` array.  Imagine 10 groups per user at 5000 users. You would have 50000 groups per user in your CSV.

Comment: @AdminOfThings does `-Properties` not limit that?

Comment: `-Properties` adds attributes to return from the objects you are querying. It does not impact the number of objects you return only the size of the returned result. `-Properties *` vs. `-Properties Attribute1,Attribute2` will likely use more memory but won't impact your CSV since you are selecting (`Select-Object`) the attriubtes you want to output. If you run `Get-ADUser username`, it will return a default list of attributes, which does not include `mail` for example. If you want to see the mail value along with the default attributes, then you must run `Get-ADUser username -Properties Mail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight augment in your code can achieve the results you want:

```
$users = get-aduser -filter "Enabled -eq '$true'" -Properties memberof, emailAddress, extensionattribute2, manager, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, url
$users | Foreach-Object {
   $groups = ForEach ($group in $_.memberof) {
     (Get-ADGroup $group).Name
   }
   $groupStr = $groups -join "; " #Change "; " to "`r`n" for line break separator

   $_ | Select-Object @{N="firstName";E={$_.GivenName}},
   @{N="lastName";E={$_.Surname}},
   @{N="email";E={$_.EmailAddress}},
   @{N="businessArea";E={$_.extensionattribute2}},
   @{N="accountName";E={$_.SamAccountName}},
   @{N="manager";E={$_.Manager -replace '^CN=|,.*$'}},
   @{N="office";E={$_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName}},
   @{N="standardProfile";E={$_.url}},
   @{n='Groups'; e={$groupStr}}
} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation "c:\out.csv"
```

In your original code, $groups contains all of the groups for all enabled AD Users if you don't pick a specific user object for `get-aduser`. This is because `$user.memberof` will return all groups for every user in the `$user` array. Imagine 10 groups per user at 5000 users. You would have 50000 groups per user in your CSV.

`-Properties` adds attributes to return from the objects you are querying. It does not impact the number of objects you return only the size of the returned result. `-Properties *` vs. `-Properties Attribute1,Attribute2` will likely use more memory but won't impact your CSV since you are selecting (`Select-Object`) the attributes you want to output. If you run `Get-ADUser username`, it will return a default list of attributes, which does not include `mail` for example. If you want to see the mail value along with the default attributes, then you must run `Get-ADUser username -Properties Mail`.

Comment: Thanks @AdminofThings works perfectly! 7.82mb down from 40gb I'd call that a success.